# How to get global variable in sphinx search

Tags: set, global-variables, sphinx, sphinxql

How to get global variable in sphinx search which I have set it custom like

SET GLOBAL @test = (1,2,3)

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES 
returns

```
+----------------------+---------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| autocommit           | 1       |
| collation_connection | libc_ci |
| query_log_format     | plain   |
| log_level            | info    |
+----------------------+---------+
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I dont think there is a direct way to 'get' them. You can just use them in queries.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx documentation http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-set has an example:

> ```
> // in session 1
> mysql> SET GLOBAL @myfilter=(2,3,5,7,11,13);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> // later in session 2
> mysql> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE group_id IN @myfilter;
> +------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
> | id   | weight | group_id | date_added | title           | tag  |
> +------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
> |    3 |      1 |        2 | 1299338153 | another doc     | 15   |
> |    4 |      1 |        2 | 1299338153 | doc number four | 7,40 |
> +------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------+------+
> 2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
> ```

So this is how you get the variable. How to show the variable content is another question and I was unable to do that. :-)